# 554 amazon error code - can't send email

Tags: amazon-ses

When I am trying to send the email via amazon I'm getting the following error:

```
554 Message rejected: Sending suspended for this account. For more information, please check the inbox of the email address associated with your AWS account.
```

It happened a couple of days ago, with the endpoint `eu-west-1`. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 7):

This seems pretty straightforward.

> Sending suspended for this account.

You have been administratively blocked from sending email...

> For more information, please check the inbox of the email address associated with your AWS account.

...and AWS has sent you a message about it, which should contain an explanation.

This is not a technical problem you can troubleshoot.  You have apparently, whether intentionally or unintentionally, triggered a disruption of your service because of an excessive bounce or complaint rate or another apparent policy violation, or perhaps a billing issue.

You'll need to address this with AWS support.